# VB Script to write Output of script to a different worksheet Ask

Tags: vbscript

I have written a Script which generates a CSV file list of AD users for a different vendor Org for our Company. Now I want to add the Output of the Script below into the 2nd Tab (Worksheet) of another Excel File which I have saved in C:.

I have appended the following code in the beginning of the script so that the output is printed to the 2nd Tab (Worksheet) of another Excel File but I am getting multiple errors for the same. The code snippet is as follows :-

```
Option Explicit
Dim xL 
Dim Targetbook 
Set Targetbook = xl.workbooks.open("C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Projects\Project automation\IM controls\Iuc.xlsx")
Dim Targetsheet
Set Targetsheet = targetbook.worksheets("IM AD users")
Dim t
Set t = targetsheet.range("a1")
```

But I am getting multiple VBScript compilation errors when I append the snippet above and run the code. What is the mistake that I am doing here ? Or also can I add after count = count +1 statement to append the output to the Other Workbook's 2nd Worksheet? I am kind of new and confused on this.

```
Option Explicit
Dim xL 
Dim Targetbook 
Set Targetbook = xl.workbooks.open("C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Projects\Project automation\IM controls\Iuc.xlsx")
Dim Targetsheet
Set Targetsheet = targetbook.worksheets("IM AD users")
Dim t
Set t = targetsheet.range("a1")

Dim objConnection,objCommand,objRecordSet,objUser,ObjFSO, InitFSO,objdialog,thisday,intreturn,OutputFile,myprompt
Dim intCounter,strfname,strDN,arrPath,stroutput,objoutput,Account_locked,Objclass,ObjMail
Dim StrEmpType,IntUAC,UserStatus,slogin,Last_Logon_timestamp,Last_Login,Last_pwd_changed,PWD_Never_Expire,objLastLogon,intLastLogonTime,intLastLogon,User_must_change_pwd



Dim objShell
Dim strFileName
Dim strFilePath
Dim objFile
Dim manager,manager1,manager2,IMSite,IMSite1,IMSite2,count

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 2
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &H10000 
Const ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD = &H0020 
Const ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 8388608
Const ADS_UF_LOCKOUT= 16

' Declare Option Constants
'------------------------
Const BIF_EDITBOX = &H10
Const BIF_NONEWFOLDER = &H0200
Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1

Dim strprompt, intoptions,strroot,strfolderpath

' Setup connection to AD
'------------------------
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection






' Specify the output file.
'-----------------------------

Msgbox " This script will generate a list of all IM AD users that are into the IM OU in the imaje.intra domain and that are enabled." & vbnewline & vbnewline  _
    & "You will be prompted to enter the location where to store the output file." _
    & vbnewline & vbnewline & " Just browse the folder where you want to save it " _
    & vbnewline & vbnewline & " You will be notified when the script will be completed . Press OK to continue"



' Generate the output filename with the date
'-------------------------------------------
thisday=Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date),2) & Right("0" & Day(Date),2)


strPrompt = "Please select the folder where to store the final output file."
intOptions = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_EDITBOX + BIF_NONEWFOLDER

' Return the path, e.g. C:\
strFolderPath = Browse4Folder(strPrompt, intOptions, "")

OutputFile = strFolderPath & "\List_IM_AD_users_" & thisday & ".csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objoutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile(OutputFile)


Msgbox " Press OK to start extracting Active Directory information for IM Users into " & OutputFile & vbnewline & vbnewline  _
    & " You'll be notified when the script will be completed !"


' Set paging file higher to accommodate lots of AD records
'-------------------------------------------------------------

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 40000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

'Prepare the LDAP command
'--------------------------

objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT AdsPath FROM 'LDAP://OU=IM,OU=MIUsers,OU=MI,DC=Imaje,DC=intra' WHERE objectCategory='user'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
objRecordSet.MoveFirst

' Read the Entire AD domain for objectCategory=user and write the various fields into the output file
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
objOutput.Write "SamAccountName;GivenName;sn;DisplayName;E-mail @;IM Site;Exists in IM list;IM location;Title;Country;Manager;employeeID;Account locked;Last Logon;LastLogon timestamp;Pwd Never Expires;Last PWD Change;User_must_change_pwd;User creation date;User Change Date;Description;DN" & vbcrlf

count=1

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Userstatus="Enabled"
    Set objUser = GetObject(objRecordSet.Fields("AdsPath").Value)

' Get status of the User ( disabled or not , pwd required or Not , User must change pwd)
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    intUAC=ObjUser.userAccountControl
    If intUAC AND ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE Then
        Userstatus="Disabled"
    End If

    If intUAC AND ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
      PWD_Never_Expire="Yes"
    Else
      pwd_never_expire="No"
    End If

    If intUAC AND ADS_UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED Then
      User_must_change_pwd="Yes"
    Else
      User_must_change_pwd="No"
    End If

    If intUAC AND ADS_UF_LOCKOUT Then
      Account_locked="Yes"
    Else
      Account_locked="No"
    End If



' Get LastLogonTimestamp , LastLogon, LastPwdChange of the User 
'------------------------------------------------------------------

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objLastLogon = objUser.Get("lastLogonTimestamp")

    intLastLogonTime = objLastLogon.HighPart * (2^32) + objLastLogon.LowPart
    intLastLogonTime = intLastLogonTime / (60 * 10000000)
    intLastLogonTime = intLastLogonTime / 1440

    Last_Logon_timestamp=intLastLogonTime + #1/1/1601#

    Set objLastLogon = objUser.Get("lastLogon")

    intLastLogon = objLastLogon.HighPart * (2^32) + objLastLogon.LowPart
    intLastLogon = intLastLogon / (60 * 10000000)
    intLastLogon = intLastLogon / 1440

    Last_Login=intLastLogon + #1/1/1601#

    On Error Goto 0

    On Error Resume Next

    sLogin = objUser.passwordLastChanged
    If Err = 0 Then
            Last_pwd_changed=sLogin
        Else
            Last_pwd_changed="Never"
        End If

    On Error Goto 0

    ObjClass = objUser.Class

    ObjMail = objUser.Mail
    manager = ""
    IMSite=""

    If ObjClass = "user" and userstatus = "Enabled" then
        On Error Resume Next
        manager1= split(objUser.Manager,",")
        manager = manager1(0)
        manager2=split(manager,"=")
        manager = manager2(1)

        IMSite1 = InStr(ObjUser.distinguishedName,",OU=IM")
        IMSite2 = Mid (ObjUser.distinguishedName,IMSite1-12,12)
        IMSite1 = split(IMSite2,"=")
        IMSite = IMSite1(1)

        count=count + 1


        objOutput.Write objUser.samaccountname &";" & objUser.GivenName &";" & objUser.sn &";" & objUser.DisplayName &";" & ObjMail & ";" & IMSite & _
        ";=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(E" & count & ",'IM employees'!C:C,1,FALSE)=E" & count & ",""Yes""),""No"")" & ";=IF(G" & count & "=""Yes"",VLOOKUP(E" & _
        count & ",'IM employees'!C:D,2,FALSE),""Missing"")" & ";" &ObjUser.Title & ";" & ObjUser.Co & ";" & Manager &";" & objUser.employeeID & ";" & _
        Account_locked & ";" & last_Login & ";" & last_Logon_timestamp & ";"& pwd_never_expire & ";"& Last_pwd_Changed & ";" _
        & User_must_change_pwd & ";" & objUser.whenCreated & ";" & objUser.whenChanged & ";" & objUser.description &";" & objUser.distinguishedName &";" & vbcrlf

    End If

' Next record in recordset
'------------------------------
    objRecordSet.MoveNext


Loop

Msgbox " Script is completed ! The file " & OutputFile & " is now ready !! "

'End Script 



Function Browse4Folder(strPrompt, intOptions, strRoot)
    Dim objFolder, objFolderItem, objShell
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, strPrompt, intOptions, strRoot) 
    If (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Browse4Folder = ""
    Else
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        Browse4Folder = objFolderItem.Path      
        Set objFolderItem = Nothing
        Set objFolder = Nothing
    End If  
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue I can see is that you are not getting a hold of excel first:

the first few lines of code should maybe be:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xL 
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim Targetbook 
Set Targetbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Projects\Project automation\IM controls\Iuc.xlsx")
Dim targetsheet
targetbook.Sheets("IM AD users").Select
Set targetsheet = targetbook.ActiveSheet    '<<<i added SET here
```

Apart from that entering data is pretty straight forward:

```
Dim currentRow : currentRow = 1

Function RecordData (username,companyCode)
    targetsheet.Cells(currentRow,1).Value = companyCode
    targetsheet.Cells(currentRow,2).Value = username
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
End Function
```

You can then call that function with data whenever you want:

```
RecordData ("2000","bobbyj")
```

You will also need to save and close the file:

```
'alerts need to be disabled so that you don't get warnings about saving over the file etc. (excel pop ups)
'ALERTS MUST BE TURNED ON AGAIN IMMEDIATELY AS THIS IS A GLOBAL SETTING FOR EXCEL 
'    - i.e. users will not get warnings about unsaved files etc. when quitting excel normally'
xl.DisplayAlerts = false
targetbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Projects\Project automation\IM controls\Iuc.xlsx")
xl.DisplayAlerts = true

'close workbook now it has been saved - there should be no pop ups'
targetbook.Close()

'release references and close excel'
set targetbook = nothing
set targetsheet = nothing

xl.Quit()

set xl = Nothing
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Can you kindly see my response on :-

https://pastebin.com/ZeK8JiVt

Comment: @AvikChowdhury you will need to write the data to the file.. using  `targetsheet.Cells(row,column).Value= something` .. i think i missed SET from the assignment of targetsheet.. see modified code.  if all this works i think you should maybe mark this as answered and hten post another question.. as ideally SO questions are supposed to be specific.